# Fever lower limit ( 99.0 °F (37.2 °C) at armpit)... is it universal?

Tags: measurement, body-temperature, fever, thermometer

Surprisingly, all professional doctors, school-textbooks and other resources, consider as armpit temperatures:

`>` 99 ° F (some-others `>` 98.6 &deg F) = Fever;
 `=` 99 ° F (Some-others `=` 98.6 &deg F) = Normal;
 `<` 99 ° F (Some-others  `<` 98.6 &deg F) = Less than normal.

But this doesn't match with my experience. I feel normal when I'm around 96 &deg F (officially which is less than normal); and 98.6 ° F is clearly perceptible as fever to me. (and this is *not* based upon a single thermometer on single event; it is based upon many).  Similarly; my mother tells 98.6 ° F is much more than a low-grade-fever whereas her normal temperature is around or below 96 ° F. On the opposite end we have seen peoples (such as my father when was youth) who did not reported any feverish or tired or such at near 100 ° F.

So it is quite surprising to me, that 99 ° F (or 98.6 ° F to some other doctors) is treated-as-definition of lower-end of  **universal** standard. **Is it really universal?** or it is just an 'average' or 'consensus' that doesn't cause serious deviation if used as an overall standard.

---

P.S. 1:  Wikipedia tells; normal temperature can vary slightly from person to person and by day of time. But I could not find any such mention about fever.

---

P.S. 2: How the human normal temperature could be only one particular value? Shouldn't there be a 'range' instead?

Comment: @PillsNPillows Too much tag. This is not an armpit question ant nor a thermometer-question. I was trying to give the measurement tag because I could not found 'standards'. It was a question about defining or standardizing of a medical condition (fever). I think the term 'armpit' could be included inside the text.

Comment: Related: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/54127/do-human-populations-differ-in-core-body-temperature ,and  http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/11039/in-japan-the-official-average-body-temperature-is-36-0-c-why-so-different-fro